# SurroundsWith Snippet for VS2012 Gives a Selection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

Since I defined the following snippet, I always get a unwanted selection when trying to use surround with.

```
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
<Header>
  <Title>Dependency Properties region</Title>
  <Shortcut>#regiondp</Shortcut>
  <Description>
    Umschliesst die Selektion mit einer region namens Dependency Properties
  </Description>
  <SnippetTypes>
    <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
    <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
  </SnippetTypes>
</Header>
<Snippet>
  <Code Language="csharp" Kind="method decl">
    <![CDATA[
        #region Dependency Properties
          $selected$
        #endregion
        ]]>
  </Code>
</Snippet>
```

When using "Surround with..." in a C# file, why is VS2010 asking me now whether I want to use "C#Snippets" or "Visual C#" snippets?

Comment: you're missing the enclosing tag for </CodeSnippet> at the attached xml

Comment: You are right, if I edit my posting I can see it, so it isn't really missing, but it doesn't appeare. I can't correct this, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is asking you because you have your own snippets and the pre installed snippets from MS that comes with Visual Studio installation.

If it's disturbs you, you can put your snippet at the following location: 
 %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#

among with all the snippets from MS.
HTH

Comment: Yes this helps. But do you know another solution? Because I consider my snippet file to be a source file and as such I want it in a path of my machine, which is included in my backups. I don't like the idea of modifying the program folder.

Comment: nope, but it's acceptable to put it there, you're not "messing" with the system, you can do it using the snippet manager (CTRL K + B) and hit the "Import" button and you can select your snippet and where do you want to have it, so you can choose the "Visual C#" instead of "My snippets" folder. that's pretty the same, but now you doing it using the IDE. anyway, it won't help for backups.

Comment: I just find this to be very bizarre, I have Expansion type snippets in My Code Snippets folder and they never ask me to choose a directory, why does the SurroundsWith snippet behave differently?